# get all instances of a model while removing duplicates based on a field while also attaching the count of the same field

Tags: django, database, orm

```
class Titlecomplaint(models.Model):
    title= models.ForeignKey("titles.title", on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    user= models.ForeignKey("auth.user", on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
```

From the model above, I need to get only one copy of every title ordered by the amount of the same titles in the model while also getting the count of the amount.

```
 the_titles= Titlecomplaint.objects.annotate(cnt=Count("title")).values_list('title', flat=True).distinct().order_by("cnt")
```

I'm trying the ORM above but it only returns integers while I need query objects to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to aggregation (Count), you can only logically receive a `dict` of `{title, count}`, because the count does not belong to any particular `Titlecomplaint` instance. Imagine, there are 3 complaints about the same title from 3 users. Which one should we select with count=3? However, if it doesn't matter which exactly `Titlecomplaint` instance is needed, it is possible to overcome with the use of `Subquery`. So, we start the same way to get pairs title=>count (move standard way by Django docs, values + annotate, order_by to clear any default ordering).

```
title_counts = Titlecomplaint.objects.order_by().values('title').annotate(cnt=Count('title'))
```

Next, let's add `cnt` for each `Titlecomplaint` using `Subquery`

```
title_counts = title_counts.filter(title=OuterRef('title')).values('cnt')
titles = Titlecomplaint.objects.annotate(cnt=Subquery(title_counts))
```

Finally, leave only 1 (random) Titlecomplaint per title and sort them by cent.

```
titles = titles.order_by('cnt', 'title').distinct('cnt', 'title')
```

The last query only works with PostgreSQL. If you have another database, you will need another solution to select distinct Titlecomplaint per title.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Alexandr Tatarinov, if amount is it possible to order it based on date when the counts are equal? Appreciated.

Comment: `titles.order_by('cnt', 'title', 'date').distinct('cnt', 'title')` should work

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of object rather than a list of values, you just need to drop `values_list` method and use the following like:

```
the_titles= Titlecomplaint.objects.annotate(cnt=Count("title")).distinct("title").order_by("cnt")
```

Comment: thank you a lot but this one doesn't remove duplicate titles.